# Google sheets - array formula (When inserting a line, keep numbering for rows below from 1)

Tags: google-sheets

Need some help with array formula.
I have some equipment list. Want to use array formu for some categories and rows

For example:
I have two categories with numbered rows from 5 to 8 and from 10 to 13.

If I insert and new row for example after row 5, then now array formula is ok from row 5 to 9, but starting wrong from rows below with wrong numbering and first items starts from 2 not from 1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq4dw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgIOS.png)

Asking for help with formula to start correctly array formula in every single categorie.

Link to my test file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16mxVl9vJN_SgFo0FF-qBuT57db-cANHLWgDcnBhEDDc/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

P.S. Sorry if this was discussed somewhere, just didn't found

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=sequence(rows(B5:B8);1;1)
```

[image]